# CNN Model Accuracy not going above 10%

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am training a model in keras consisting of 6 custom blocks of CNN. I am using tensorflow 2 with keras and using categorical cross entropy with adam optimizer. The dataset consist of 55000 images. I am using 20 epochs for training.

The model generation function:

```
def generateModel(class_count):
  return keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255),
 
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_1_a"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_1_b"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_1_c"),

 
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_2_a"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_2_b"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_2_c"),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((1,1)),   
 
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_3_a"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_3_b"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_3_c"),

    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_4_a"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_4_b"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_4_c"),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((1,1)),

    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_5_a"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_5_b"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_5_c"),
 
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_6_a"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_6_b"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_6_c"),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    keras.layers.Dense(512,activation=keras.activations.tanh),
    keras.layers.Dense(256,activation=keras.activations.tanh),
    keras.layers.Dense(128,activation=keras.activations.tanh),
    keras.layers.Dense(class_count,activation=keras.activations.softmax)
])
```

My main problem is that the accuracy begins with value between 0.09 and 0.1 and it also ends with that range. The model accuracy not increasing and you can call it almost stable. I also tried to reduce the number of filter channels setting them to 32 in each block but still the same happens. I do not know what is happening.

Update:

**[dataset link](https://data.mendeley.com/public-files/datasets/tywbtsjrjv/files/d5652a28-c1d8-4b76-97f3-72fb80f94efc/file_downloaded)**

The dataset loading function. The path variable accepts the path to the root location of the stored images like /home/username/PLantDiseaseDataset/* where * can be any class name folder consisting of the images:

```
def getDataset(path):
  dataset={}
  dataset['training']=keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(dataset_location,label_mode='categorical',batch_size=32,image_size=(256,256),seed=1,validation_split=0.1,subset='training')
  dataset['validation']=keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(dataset_location,label_mode='categorical',batch_size=32,image_size=(256,256),seed=1,validation_split=0.1,subset='validation')
  return dataset
```

The function that generates the model is

```
def generateModel(class_count):
  return keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255),
 
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_1_a"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_1_b"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_1_c"),

 
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_2_a"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_2_b"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_2_c"),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((1,1)),   
 
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_3_a"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_3_b"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_3_c"),

    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_4_a"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_4_b"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_4_c"),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((1,1)),

    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_5_a"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_5_b"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_5_c"),
 
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_6_a"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_6_b"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),padding='valid',activation=keras.activations.relu,name="Conv_6_c"),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    keras.layers.Dense(512,activation=keras.activations.tanh),
    keras.layers.Dense(256,activation=keras.activations.tanh),
    keras.layers.Dense(128,activation=keras.activations.tanh),
    keras.layers.Dense(class_count,activation=keras.activations.softmax)
])
```

The function that trains the model is

```
def train_model(model,dataset):
  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
  history=model.fit(dataset['validation'],epochs=10)
  return history
```

The calling of all functions and execution statements are

```
dataset_location=<Root location of the images i.e. the path variable value>
dataset=getDataset(dataset_location)
model=generateModel(len(dataset['training'].class_names))
history=train_model(model,dataset)
```

I have trained the model on 10% of dataset with 10 epochs so this is the result is

```
Epoch 1/10
  2/174 [..............................] - ETA: 2:37 - loss: 3.6052 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0625WARNING:tensorflow:Callbacks method `on_train_batch_end` is slow compared to the batch time (batch time: 0.2761s vs `on_train_batch_end` time: 0.7887s). Check your callbacks.
174/174 [==============================] - 180s 1s/step - loss: 3.4654 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0931
Epoch 2/10
174/174 [==============================] - 176s 1s/step - loss: 3.4134 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0979
Epoch 3/10
174/174 [==============================] - 177s 1s/step - loss: 3.4111 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0936
Epoch 4/10
174/174 [==============================] - 177s 1s/step - loss: 3.4097 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0974
Epoch 5/10
174/174 [==============================] - 176s 1s/step - loss: 3.4127 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0936
Epoch 6/10
174/174 [==============================] - 176s 1s/step - loss: 3.4091 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0925
Epoch 7/10
174/174 [==============================] - 176s 1s/step - loss: 3.4102 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0952
Epoch 8/10
174/174 [==============================] - 176s 1s/step - loss: 3.4084 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0913
Epoch 9/10
174/174 [==============================] - 176s 1s/step - loss: 3.4109 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0924
Epoch 10/10
174/174 [==============================] - 176s 1s/step - loss: 3.4107 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0940
```

Hope this might also help

Comment: Hi Vedant, please share thhe code you use to load the dataset, initialize and train the model. This error seems to be linked to something wrong elsewhere. The model definition looks correct.

Comment: yaa sure I will update it

Comment: @VedantGandhi Try changing the optimizer of your model.

Comment: Can you suggest any

Comment: Ok, now please share the code to train the model

Comment: OK I will do it

Comment: I'm quite confident this has nothing to do with the choice of optimizer. The model is not learning at all

Comment: so far everything looks correct. I guess you're using the MNIST dataset. Can you add enough code for other people to test it?

Comment: can you try changing your loss to "sparse_categorical_crossentropy". This is only needed if you are providing the target as a class label instead of a one hot.

Comment: Actually I am testing on the plant village dataset

Comment: @AkshaySehgal The labels according to tensorflow documentations are one hot encoded because when using image dataset from directory if the label mode is set to categorical it automatically gives a one hot encoded vector

Comment: @ibarrond I will give the code to you surely along with the dataset link

Comment: @ibarrond is the code enough or is more needed?

Comment: can you share the code? it might be easier for once

Comment: @ibarrond This is  my code I have done it on Google colab so it is splitted into functions

Comment: Its hard to debug unless I can replicate the issue at my end. Dont see anything glaringly wrong in code. Can you remove `keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255),` and instead do that outside the model?

Comment: I do not know how to do that because the dataset loads as the object of BatchDataset specific to tensorflow and not numpy array so it is hard to directly do that but i will check it out

Comment: Ok understand. Take a look in your data set directory. Make sure it only has subdirectories associated with the classes. Make sure there are no extraneous files in the data set directory. Then look in the class subdirectories and make sure it contains only image files. I forget which types of image files are acceptable, for sure jpg and png so you might want to check the extensions. Finally is the data set for training close to being balanced? That is what is the comparative ratio of the number of image files in each class directory.

Comment: @GerryP Yes sir actually the dataset is directly downloaded into the Google colab and extraced there itself.I have the same copy of the dataset on my device There are about 1000 images in each directory and yes the root directory consist of the subdirectories only associated with the classes.As fot the image extension every image is of JPG format

Comment: Hmm- only thing I can think of to try to isolate the problem is to change your model using transfer learning, for example use Mobilenet, If that trains correctly you will know the problem is in the model. If it does not then the problem is with the data or how it is feed to the model, code to use Mobilenet is shown in my modified answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help isolate the cause of the problem I suggest you use a model that is known to work. I suggest Mobilenet. If the mobilenet model trains well then the problem is in your model. If it does not train well then the problem is with the data or the way the data is feed to the model. Code to use Mobilenet is shown below. Mobilenet needs the images to be 224 X 224 so change that in your data set.

```
img_shape=(224,224)
base_model=tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet( include_top=False, input_shape=img_shape, pooling='max', weights='imagenet',dropout=.4) 
x=base_model.output
x = Dense(64, kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(l = 0.016),activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006),
                bias_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006) ,activation='relu')(x)
x=Dropout(rate=.3 seed=123)(x) 
output=Dense(class_count, activation='softmax',)(x)
model=Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)
model.compile(Adamax(lr=.001 ), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics='accuracy')
```

Comment: No I am training on the training dataset only but I tried to just train it on validation set so that I could verify that the accuracy is increasing or not by an estimate

Comment: Yeah sir this solution is working and I guess I have to develop more efficient model.THank you so much

Comment: most wecome. My advise is to use a fairly simple model initially then add to it if needed